# Making false sudoku coordinate red

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku, coordinate

Yoo, hope this isn't too specific. 
I'm making a sudoku and I got method that takes care of all the false x and y-coordinates for every wrong (to make them go red); which I layer in a string. If I find an incorrect number I layer the coordinates as: x,y  for every wrong and then add more like: x,y,x,y,x,y ...
SudokuResultCount is my other class where I keep the coordinates, and FalseCoordinates is the string where I keep them. So when I press "Correct my sudoku"-button this method goes.

This is made in this method:

```
public static void totalfalsecoordinates(int array[][], int array2[][]){
        SudokuResultCount.setFalseCoordinates("");


        for(int x=0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y < 9; y++){
                try{
                    if(array2[x][y] != array[x][y]&& array2[x][y] != 0)
                    {
                        SudokuResultCount.setFalseCoordinates(x + y + "");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I run this method later on in this method:

```
try{
            int falseCoordinatesLength = SudokuResultCount.getFalseCoordinates().length();
            if(falseCoordinatesLength > 0)
            {
                SudokuMetoder.totalfalsecoordinates(KeepingUpWithTheSudokus.getSolution(), KeepingUpWithTheSudokus.getStartingvalues());
                int targetStringchar = 0;
                int targetStringchar1= 1;
                int numbersOfLoops = SudokuResultCount.getFalseCoordinates().length();
                int realnumbersOfLoops = numbersOfLoops/2;
                for(int number = 0; number < realnumbersOfLoops; targetStringchar = targetStringchar + 2, targetStringchar1 = targetStringchar1 + 2, number++){
                    char a_char = SudokuResultCount.getFalseCoordinates().charAt(targetStringchar);
                    char b_char = SudokuResultCount.getFalseCoordinates().charAt(targetStringchar1);
                    int x = Character.getNumericValue(a_char);
                    int y = Character.getNumericValue(b_char);
                    System.out.println(y);
//                  int x = (int)a_char;
//                  int y = (int)b_char;
                    textFields[x][y].setStyle("-fx-border-color: red ; -fx-border-width: 2px ;");
                }   
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e3){
                String str = "2" + "2" + "";                            
                char b_char = str.charAt(0);
                int x = Character.getNumericValue(b_char);
                System.out.println(x);
                textFields[2][3].setStyle("-fx-border-color: red ; -fx-border-width: 2px ;");
                textFields[2][3].setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent, #909090, transparent, red;");
            }
```

If the number of the string length > 0 then search through. And since I take two numbers from the String at one time, I take the length of the String and divide it by two.

Then I make them into characters so I can decide which one to take. 
If I go through the coordinates: 0,1
Any wrongs? Ok then make array[0][1] shine red - otherwise move on. 
Then it moves 0,1 2,3 4,5 ...

Ask for removal if too specific!

thanks

Comment: TL;DR; I suspect that the long explanation and code hides a simple question. Are you asking how to output red text to the console ?

Comment: I'm trying to make false coordinates which are textfields in a sudoku (array 2d) go red when the user entered wrong number/s.

Comment: I did not get an answer to what I asked. Too much irrelevant info and too little essential info. Please post [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Won't most likely help anyone, but I found the answer. It messed up where I added x + y + "" into the String in which i layered the coordinates. I had to do: "" + x + "" + y + ""